# CSS reference link blocked in HTML document

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am referencing a CSS link in my HTML document. I am able to open the index.html file via live server but when I host the link on S3 with HTTPS enabled it does not display the website properly I believe due to the fact that my S3 website endpoint is in HTTPS but the stylesheet link is only in HTTP.

Here is the ref link below which works out:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css" />
```

I get the following error through the developer console when I try to access the website via https

The resource from “https://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

How would I be able to proceed to allow this CSS link to be accessible through S3 HTTPS website if the link is in http?

I have removed the http tag so that it could redirect to https but that did not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css" />
```

When I add the HTTPS tag infront, it doesn't display the website normally due to the css ref not accessble via https.

Comment: https://yui.yahooapis.com/ says "Yahoo Logo
Will be right back...

Thank you for your patience.

Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue." Such are the perils of depending on third party servers.

Comment: Note that YUI is no longer supported, and YUI 2 was superseded by YUI 3 in 2009! You really should modernise your code base.

Comment: (Re-reads his first comment: And that people is why the `alt` attribute should contain a *replacement* for the image and not a *description* of it).

Answer (score 0):

https://yui.yahooapis.com/2.7.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css is currently yielding a 404 for me and a HTML page (which confirms why you're getting a `text/html` MIME content type for a CSS file).

[image]

Use a local copy meanwhile, or wait until it's working again.